# How to add color chooser/filter to a website?

Tags: magento, color-picker

I am using Magento. And I need to add a color chooser to my website based on which the search results will be filtered. For example, say its a shopping site and the user chooses "blue" from the color panel, then all the blue colored products will be displayed in the search result.

P.S: I am not talking about the Magento color swatches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel, go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`, then find the attribute you are using for color and click on it. You will find a dropdown option **Use In Layered Navigation** and select **Filterable (with results)**. That's it.